# How can I access the next data?

Tags: php, json

I am extracting the name of each element from `https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/`

I'm doing this as so:

```
$foo = json_decode($foo, true);
$name = $foo['data'][`1`]['name'];
```

Which will give me `Bitcoin`. But how do I move onto the next element? Right now I am physically setting the `['1']` to be 1 which is Bitcoin. And as you can see from the data, its all random numbers to. Its not 1, 2, 3, 4. Its 1, 1027, 52 etc. So Essentially, do I do access the next element?

Comment: Never heard of foreach? If you use foreach, you can get the indexes and keep looping without knowing their name, getting just the content.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Use `foreach($foo['data']) as $data)` then you can get the name by `$data['name']` inside the foreach.